# Run Liquibase with Azure CICD pipeline

Tags: maven, azure-devops, liquibase

I want to run my Database updates with liquibase commands. I have added all the required  details and configured the liquibase.properties files in my project. Everything works fine with local deployments. Now I am using Azure CICD pipeline to deploy the code into my higher environments.

I want to run `mvn liquibase:update -Pdev` command from the pipeline. When I run this as a maven task in `azure-pipelines.yml`, I get `"liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:postgresql: ...etc"`.

How I can run the mvn liquibase commands with the pipeline? I do not have persmission to allow CICD server to access the DB server directly. Any alternative mechanism also would be helpful.

Comment: As it works fine locally, and you do not have permission to allow CICD server to access the DB server directly, you can try to configure a [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#install).

Comment: On each db is a firewall config...so you should ask some admin to grant an access to it from your CICD env...otherwise you would need to do some workarounds which is not worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by granting some access to the pipeline in the Azure environment. I had to change an NSG(network security group) rule so that the Azure build servers (VMSS) could reach the database (postgress DB) over port 5432 in each environment.